# De Moivre's theorem and the n-th root of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

[The Question is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVnhx.png)

Using De Moivre’s Theorem, show that
$\cos(4θ) = 8\sin^4θ−8\sin^2θ+1$.
Hence, by utilizing the above equation, obtain all possible roots for the
equation
$16y^4 − 16y^2 + 1=0$.

Hi,
I'm having trouble to find solution for this question. Please help me with this. I can't find same question like this.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.